# Unpack custom data fields in SystemVerilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, uvm

I'm trying to write a generic register parser for SystemVerilog symulation (not synthesizable).
The goal is to return an array of fields, given:

- fields position
- fields width
- register value

Here's my take:

```
  task automatic reg_parser( ref    int apb_word,
                             ref    int lsb_array[],
                             ref    int width_array[],
                             output int fields_array[] );

    // Extract right bits
    // field  = word[FIELD_LSB+FIELD_WIDTH-1 : FIELD_LSB];
    for (int i = 0; i < $size(fields_array); i++) begin
      fields_array[i] = apb_word[lsb_array[i]+width_array[i]-1:lsb_array[i]];
    end
  endtask : reg_parser
```

The problem is that `vlog` is complaining: `range must be bounded by constant expressions`.
I found [examples](https://www.amiq.com/consulting/2017/05/29/how-to-pack-data-using-systemverilog-streaming-operators/#advanced_packing) with streaming operators (`>>`,`<<`), but they imply constant regular structures, while register fields are often not so regular.

Any suggestions on how to correctly implement this?

Answer (score 0):

As part select will not work due to non-constant size of the "field". I would rotate and mask the value.

```
for (int i = 0; i < $size(fields_array); i++) begin
  int mask;
  //Create mask which is of width of your field, by rotation
  mask = 32'hFFFF_FFFF >> (32 - width_array[i]);
  //Rotate the APB_WORD so that the lsb postion as at 0 postion 
  //and mask the value.
  fields_array[i] = mask&(apb_word >> lsb_array[i]);
  // fields_array[i] = apb_word[lsb_array[i]+width_array[i]-1:lsb_array[i]];
end
```

You can also create the mask by rotating the 1 times width, and then subtract one. If I remember this correctly UVM does it in similiar way for `uvm_reg`.

```
mask = (1 << width_array[i]) - 1;
```

By not using the decalration of the `mask`` and creating the mask in the assignment you can make it a one-liner.

```
fields_array[i] = ((1 << width_array[i]) - 1) & (apb_word >> lsb_array[i]);
```

Comment: thanks fot the reply. I pass to the task arrays of `int`. W/ your solution I still got the error: the problem lies in `width_array[i]` which must be constant, but I need to pass it as argument because the `width` varies between each field.

Comment: @a_bet yes you are actually correct. I've overlooked it. Will update the answer. I have a solution but probably someone has better and more eloquent one :-)